# Selecting table in Oracle database in SPARQL

Tags: oracle, sparql

I using SPARQL query to get rows from table TRIPLES

```
"SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }"
```

But I've got error that table or view doesn't exist. I think that it doesn't work because in this query no info about selecting tables. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct - you need to add a FROM clause, as in

`SELECT *` **FROM TRIPLES** `WHERE ...`

Share and enjoy